# Problemas al retornar Quantity me tira NaN React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy haciendo un ecommerce y tengo problemas con el Quantity que me devuelve NaN.
Funciona todo pero en vez de devolverme un numero, me da NaN en los lugares que dibuja la cantidad.

Error de la consola:

[image: Error de la consola]

CartContext.js:

```
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';

export const CartContext = createContext();

const CartContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [cartList, setCartList] = useState([]);
    const addToCart = (item, qty) => {
        // preguntar si item ya existe en el array (si ya existe no colocarlo)
        // si no existe recien ahi colocar el item
        let encontrado = cartList.find(product => product.id === item.id);
        if ( encontrado === undefined) {
            setCartList([
                ...cartList,
                {
                    id: item.id,
                    imagen: item.imagen[0],
                    titulo: item.titulo,
                    precio: item.precio,
                    qtyItem: qty
                }
            ]);
        } else {
            // si fue encontrado se aumenta el qty del producto
            encontrado.qtyItem += qty;
        }
    }
    const removeList = () => {
        setCartList([]);
    }
    const deleteItem = (id) => {
        let resultado = cartList.filter(item => item.idItem !== id);
        setCartList(resultado);
    }
    const calcItemsQty = () => {
        let qtys = cartList.map(item => item.qty);
        return qtys.reduce(((previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue), 0);
    }
    return(
        <CartContext.Provider value={{cartList, addToCart, removeList, deleteItem, calcItemsQty}}>
            { children }
        </CartContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default CartContextProvider;
```

Cart.js:

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { CartContext } from './CartContext'
import SentimentVeryDissatisfiedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SentimentVeryDissatisfied';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Cart = () => {
    const test = useContext(CartContext);
    return(
        <>
        <h1>SOY UN CARRITO</h1>
        <hr />
        {
            test.cartList.length === 0 
            ? <li className="carrito_vacio_text"><SentimentVeryDissatisfiedIcon /> No agregaste ningun producto al carrito <SentimentVeryDissatisfiedIcon /></li>
            : test.cartList.map(item => <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Producto</th>
                <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                <th scope="col">Precio</th>
                <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">{item.id}</th>
                <td>{item.imagen}</td>
                <td>{item.titulo}</td>
                <td>${item.precio}</td>
                <td>{item.qtyItem}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>)
        }
        {
          test.cartList.length === 0
          ? <button className="btn_seguir_comprando"><Link to="/">Ir al listado</Link></button>
          : <p className="parrafo_compra_carrito">¡GRACIAS POR CONFIAR EN NOSOTROS!</p>
        }
        </>
    )
}

export default Cart;
```

Comment: Y ¿Dónde esta `Quantity`?

Comment: En el addToCart del CartContext.js

Answer (score 1):

Pude solucionarlo modificando el codigo del CartContext.js de esta forma.

```
const addToCart = (item, qty) => {
    // preguntar si item ya existe en el array (si ya existe no colocarlo)
    // si no existe recien ahi colocar el item
    let encontrado = cartList.find(product => product.id === item.id);
    if (encontrado) {
    const carritoActualizado = cartList.map((prod)=>{
        if(prod.id === item.id){
            return {...prod, qty: prod.qtyItem + qty}
        }
       })
       setCartList(carritoActualizado)
    
    } else {
    // si fue encontrado se aumenta el qty del producto
    setCartList([
        ...cartList,
        {
        id: item.id,
        imagen: item.imagen[0],
        titulo: item.titulo,
        precio: item.precio,
        qtyItem: qty,
        }
    ])
    }
    }
```

y abajo de todo modifique el calcItemQty asi

```
    const calcItemsQty = () => {
    return cartList.reduce(((acc, prod) => acc + prod.qtyItem), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar inicializarla con un valor de 0 en lugar de dejarla sin inicializar. Esto se puede hacer dentro del método addToCart, en la línea donde se crea el objeto que se agrega a la lista de carrito. Por ejemplo:

```
const addToCart = (item, qty) => {
  let encontrado = cartList.find(product => product.id === item.id);
  if (encontrado === undefined) {
    setCartList([
      ...cartList,
      {
        id: item.id,
        imagen: item.imagen[0],
        titulo: item.titulo,
        precio: item.precio,
        // inicializar qty con un valor de 0
        qtyItem: qty || 0,
      }
    ]);
  } else {
    // si fue encontrado se aumenta el qty del producto
    encontrado.qtyItem += qty;
  }
}
```

De esta manera, si el parámetro qty no es proporcionado o es undefined, se asignará 0 a la propiedad qtyItem del producto en el carrito. Esto evitará que se muestre NaN en la interfaz del usuario.

Comment: Hola Cristian! Intente cambiando eso y me sigue tirando NaN con el mismo error en consola.